# How can I arrange columns in a data frame based on other columns while keeping some coulmn items constant

Tags: python, pandas

I have been stuck on this problem for days and would appreciate any help!

```
data = {"Fruit": ['Apples', 'Apples', 'Apples', 'Apples', 'Bananas', 'Bananas', 'Bananas', 'Bananas'],
           "Prices": [4.2, 3.5, 4.1, 3.8, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 5.1],
            "Market PLace": ['Main Market', 'Apple bee', 'Jamal apples', 'Bazzar mall', 'Banana Peel', 'Daimond Fruits', 'Main Market', 'Apple bee']
           }
```

The output should be like:

```
data = {"Fruit": ['Apples', 'Apples', 'Bananas', 'Bananas'],
           "Prices": [4.2, 4.1, 5.1, 1.5],
            "Market PLace": ['Main Market', 'Jamal apples', 'Apple bee', 'Main Market']
           }
```

The position of fruits does not change (i.e first top most expensive fruit of the same catagory, then another catagory), but the price of each fruit is arranged from in descending order for each 2 fruits.

I have tried using data.sort_values(['Fruit', 'Prices']), but that would not arrange the dataframe in descending order (the 2 most expensive fruit prices).

It will be easier to do this by dividing up the fruits into two data frames (apples and bananas) and then arrange each in descending order using ascending=False; use .head(2) to get top 2 fruits. But I do not know how to do go about it, and more importantly the fruit list is very large.

I am writing on Pandas and Python 3
Thank you in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you shared the complete dataframe code. What you shared is a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

This might help;

You need to combine the `sort_values` function with groupby(); the `head` function gets you the top two most expensive fruits.

```
labels = (
    df.sort_values(["Fruit", "Prices"], ascending=[True, False])
    .groupby("Fruit")
    .Prices.head(2)
    .index
)

df.loc[labels]


   Fruit    Prices  Market PLace
0   Apples  4.2 Main Market
2   Apples  4.1 Jamal apples
7   Bananas 5.1 Apple bee
6   Bananas 1.5 Main Market
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. It worked and it is intuitive as well.